# How to check web page loading delay

Tags: nginx, pm2

Server: Linux @20.04
Framework: Nuxt3 @3.2.3
DB: mongod @6.0.8
Web Server: Nginx @1.18.0
Node: @16.20.1

My website is built as Nuxt3 and distributed as PM2
Nginx has http2 and SSL
It runs as a PM2 cluster.

However, for unknown reasons, the site is being delayed for the first time for more than 10 seconds.
How to find a delay point?

Log? Scan of Chrome browser?
need a reasonable method